# $http.post enters success function even if status Unauthorized 403

Tags: angularjs, request

I have the following code for a login form:

```
function(loginData) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var data = {
        "email": loginData.email,
        "password": loginData.password,
        "remember": loginData.remember
    };
    $http.post(CONSTANTS.baseURL + '/login', data)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            _authenticate(data);
            //redirects to home
            $state.go('home');
            // location.hash = "#/home";
            deferred.resolve(true);
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            //show error message
            _logout();
            deferred.resolve(false);
            return false;
        });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Debugging the code always triggers the .success function.
The status of the request is 403. The status param from .success function is also 403

```
Request Method:POST
Status Code:403 Forbidden
```

Comment: This is also happening to me but with a `PUT status code: 403`. This might just be what happens by default for 403.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem to you and found that the reason was because I had previously configured a $httpProvider intercept::

```
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
});
```

On removing this, my error callback was correctly being called.

Another Ref: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2609

Comment: indeed, I have an interceptor. But I can't get rid of it. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q, $rootScope) {
    return {
        'responseError': function(rejection) {
            switch (rejection.status) {
                case 500:
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('server:error');
                    break;
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection); //<-important
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: From Review:  Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks